# limit maximum concurrent systemd "start jobs" at boot time (ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: boot, systemd, hdparm

At boot time I am getting 18 start jobs all trying to start which causes failures. I want to limit the maximum concurrent start jobs to either 1 or 2. How do I do this.

I have increased all the timers but still get failures in start jobs:-
DefaultTimeoutStartSec=300s
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=300s
DefaultTimeoutAbortSec=300s
DefaultRestartSec=15000ms
DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec=180s
DefaultStartLimitBurst=60s

I also noticed that the hard disk write cache is off & the read ahead is 255,
perhaps it possible to change these at boot, to cache on & say 8 for read ahead.

Comment: changed DefaultStartLimitBurst=60  (added s by mistake)

Comment: the boot time is about 5-10 mins, clearly too much is going on at the same time, the disk is 500GB which I feel is too slow. To clear these 18 jobs take about 2-3 mins

Comment: Going to try DefaultRestartSec=120000ms and reduce the other timers to 30s

Comment: I think the root cause is the hard drive & the kernel 5.8.25 with slow boot problem

ATA device, with non-removable media
 Model Number:       WDC WD5000AVDS-63U7B1                   
 Serial Number:      WD-WMAV93481626
 Firmware Revision:  01.00A01
 Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6

Comment: In recovery mode the kernel is loaded in 15 seconds. In normal mode it takes 162 seconds. The kernel option recovery seems to fix the system. When resumed from recovery the system is slow again. I do not see loading ram disk as 1st line on boot-up. There are high wa in top & vmstat -d disk write ms is > 100000

Comment: I think its grub option recovery